# How do I show how much questions have been answered? C# Console Application

Tags: c#

kind of having an issue... I would like to know in which area can I show the amount of questions that have been answered? If you scroll down, you'll see the questions that are there so far. Below that, you will see what attempt I have made. I would like it if you could assist me with this. Also I am definitely not an expert at programming, I know how the functions work but just not too well...

```
                var questions = new List<Question>()

    {
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Attack On Titan] Which character is the 'Rogue' Titan?", Answer = "Eren"},
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Pokemon] Which Pokemon does Ash use mostly?", Answer = "Pikachu" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Fairy Tail] Who raised Natsu Dragneel when he was a child?", Answer = "Igneel" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Death Note] What was Light's surname?", Answer = "Yagami" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Attack On Titan] Who was Eren's best friend?", Answer = "Armin" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Attack On Titan] Which character is the'Armored' Titan?", Answer = "Reiner" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Attack On Titan] Which character is the 'Colossal' Titan?", Answer = "Bertholt" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Death Note] In the series, there was always a shinigami with Light Yagami, what was their name?", Answer = "Ryuk" },
        new Question { Text = "Q. [Attack On Titan] Who gave Mikasa their red scarf?", Answer = "Eren" },
    };

                Random random = new Random();

                foreach (var question in questions.OrderBy(q => random.Next()))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(question.Text);

                    do
                    {
                        var answer = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (question.IsCorrect(answer))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("That is correct!" + 1 / 100); // My attempt :[
                            Thread.Sleep(800);
                            Console.Clear();

                        Console.WriteLine("You are incorrect.");
                    }
                    while (true);
                }
```

Comment: What is your question: how to count or how to display?

Comment: Please read [MCVE] guidance on posting code. ASCII art  in code is a bit more acceptable than code in art or images, but very unlikely to be directly related to the question you have and makes it confusing what you actually have problem with.

Comment: @Plutonix I want to display the questions answered in this format (0/100)

Comment: You only have 9 questions, so where does the 100 come from?  All in all, isnt is just counting?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour] to get the most from the site.

Comment: Before answer declare a variable: `int correctAnswers = 0;`. Then instead of `1/100`, change it to `Console.WriteLine("That is correct! {0}/100", correctAnswers);`.

Comment: I'll try it now :) thank you @CodingYoshi

Comment: `correctAnswers` will need to be declared outside of the `foreach` loop otherwise you will never get a value great than 1.

Comment: You also have other issues. You have an infinite loop in `do while` because `true` will always be `true`. Also @MattStannett is correct in his comment above.

Comment: @CodingYoshi How can I get it out of an infinite loop?

Comment: @Saifur just remove the while loop. why do u have it there?

Comment: Please don't update your question with a new question after the first one has been answered.  You would be better to post a new question (linking to this one if it helps).

Comment: My bad, and will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an integer variable outside of your `foreach` loop to keep track of how many questions have been answered correctly, inside your `foreach` loop increment that variable if the user gets the question right, then you can print out the variable to the console.

An example:

```
int correctAnswers = 0;

foreach(var question in questions.OrderBy(q => random.Next()))
{
    Console.WriteLine(question.Text);
    string answer = "";

    do
    {
        answer = Console.ReadLine();

        if (question.IsCorrect(answer))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"That is correct! {++correctAnswers}/100");

            Thread.Sleep(800);
            Console.Clear();

            Console.WriteLine("You are incorrect.");
         }
    }
    while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(answer));
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking and does not answer the question.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: I'll try this now :)

Comment: @MattStannett  this line: while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(answer)); shows an error at (answer));

Comment: @Saifur fixed, we had to declare `answer` outside of the `do-while` loop so that we can access it in the `while` portion.

Comment: @MattStannett there is however, just one issue. Once i enter a correct answer for any question, the output displays 0/100 and once I answer the second question it shows 1/100; after I enter the answer for the second question that's when the count goes up. Is it the int correctAnswers which is causing that issue?

Comment: @MattStannett Accepted bro

Comment: @Saifur you are corerct! We need to increment the value before we print it out. Replace `correctAnswers++` with `++correctAnswers`. XD

Comment: @MattStannett Thank you for this bro :) everything working good now.